# Am I monkeypatching jQueryUI ProgressBar correctly in this example?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-progressbar

I've got a full bore copy of jQuery UI in the app, so it doesn't matter if I'm loading from the CDN or locally, all I know is it's loaded. (because if we load from the CDN our only option is to monkeypatch the live version, yes?)

I see from: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.js that `this.min` is unfortunately not a settable option (`this.options.max` in contrast). I need `this.min` to be `-1` in my case (and yes, application wide, we have discussed this internally on the team and we understand the reason for the jQuery decision, we just need it to be otherwise), so my only options seem to be to monkeypatch the prototype or maintain my own plugin. I also see that they are using the "widget" architecture now, for loading the jQuery UI objects.

In this particular application, my scripts are roughly loaded like so:

```
/javascripts/lib/jquery.min.js
/javascripts/lib/jquery-ui.min.js
...
/javascripts/company.utils.js
/javascripts/company.helpers.js
...
page level includes of javascript libraries
...
page level javascript
```

So I'm thinking of going into company.utils.js and define a monkeypatch like so:

```
$.ui.progressbar.prototype.min = -1;
```

However, I'm curious if this is the right way to monkeypatch this object. Pretty sure it is, but thought I would ask the wider StackOverflow community, and offer something googlable for future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Alternatively, if you're using jQuery UI 1.9, you can use the widget factory to define your extension:

```
$.widget( "ui.progressbar", $.ui.progressbar, {
    min: -1
});
```

Though it is slightly more verbose.

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, I can monkeypatch the prototype like _that_? That seems much less prone to future breakage ...